# Code required to run a query on the first day of each month

Tags: sql-server

I would like to run a query on a MS SQL Server 2014 on the first day of the month, every month.
Would any of the following be ok?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),GETDATE(),104)=1
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE DATEPART(d,GETDATE())=1
```

or

```
SELECT column_a, MAX(column_b)
FROM Table
WHERE column_c=value
GROUP BY column_a
HAVING DATEPART(d,GETDATE())=1
```

Tnx

Comment: No.  Nothing in a query specifies when it is run.  If you want to *run* a query on the first of the month, then use SQL Server Agent and schedule it monthly for the first day of the month.

Comment: Can you give more context here?  Your queries would seem to return all _records_ when the day is the first day of the month (returning nothing otherwise).  Is this the behavior you really want?

Comment: My wish is to have the query generate results when the day is the first day of the month. The selection is only an example. Tnx.